# Yang–Mills theory and mass gap

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I am interested in widening my knowledge into the formal aspects of Yang–Mills theory. In particular, I would like to study the current mathematical and physical research literature about this argument and about the 'Yang–Mills existence and mass gap' problem which is phrased as follows:

*Prove that for any compact simple gauge group $\rm G$, a non-trivial quantum Yang–Mills theory exists on $\mathbb {R} ^{4}$ and has a mass gap $\Delta > 0$.*

The literature about this argument is wide and complex. Is there anyone who may suggest me some introductory paper? Maybe a review of the state of art. Consider that I have quite good basis in functional analysis and about quantum field theories from a point of view of mathematical physics (as regard the latest point). I would thank you if you can indicate me also more advanced papers so that I can have an idea of the current state of the art about this topic once I will have finished the introductory review(s).

Thank you in advance if you can help me,

Kel

Comment: You can read this papers: https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.05292, https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08182, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.06184.

Comment: Check this link at Physics Overflow https://physicsoverflow.org/21786/energy-mass-spectrum-yang-mills-bosons-infinite-and-discrete?show=21846#a21846

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether you've done this already, but the natural thing to do seems to be to read the [official statement of the problem and its status](http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/yang%E2%80%93mills-and-mass-gap).

Answer (score 1):

You can find a useful survey in these recent [talk slides](https://www.newton.ac.uk/files/seminar/20180712100011001-1323010.pdf) by Sourav Chatterjee.